# Adding network folder to finder favorites

Tags: applescript, finder

I am trying to write an apple script that adds a certain folder from a server that has been mapped to the favorites section in finder.

What I have so far is:

```
tell application "finder

activate

open "path to server" 

tell application :System Events"

keystroke "t" using {command down, control down}

  end tell

end tell
```

I believe that the problem is with "path to server", I do not need the location opened just placed in the favorites section.

The result is error "finder got an error: Handler cant handle objects of this class.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The result is error "finder got an error: Handler cant handle objects of this class.

Comment: It is best to edit your original post with that error.

Comment: if you can show the actual path you are using might help someone help here.  Also it looks like you've re typed that script into the browser here, it's missing a few quotes etc. Better to cut and paste from ScriptEditor instead